# Prototype Js Multiple Selector

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

This is my css path:

```
#product_composite_configure .entry-edit .buttons-set.a-right .scalable
```

How do I select this using prototype js ? I want to add a new attribute to this item.

This doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('#product_composite_configure .entry-edit .buttons-set.a-right .scalable').setAttribute("test","test");
</script>
```

Thx

**[UPDATE]**

This doesn't work too:

```
$$('div#product_composite_configure div.entry-edit div.buttons-set button.scalable').setAttribute("test","test");
```

Comment: First, why are you using prototype? It hasn't had a commit in almost a year... and that's a loooong time in JavaScript land...

Comment: I have to :( its not my choice

Comment: @JaredSmith Maybe it just reached the optimum with nothing to improve? :-P

Comment: @Bergi You mean like the Common Lisp spec? :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$$()` selector returns an array of the selected elements. So you would need to iterate over the array or user the built-in iterator `invoke()`.

for example

```
$$('.css_class').invoke('writeAttribute','checked',true);
```

or your CSS selector

```
$$('#product_composite_configure .entry-edit .buttons-set.a-right .scalable').invoke('writeAttribute',"test","test");
```

I used `writeAttribute()` instead of `setAttribute()` as it works in all browsers PrototypeJS supports

There are a few other ways to make this work as well

```
$('product_composite_configure').down('.entry-edit .buttons-set.a-right .scalable').writeAttribute('test','test');

$$('#product_composite_configure .entry-edit .buttons-set.a-right .scalable')[0].writeAttribute('test','test');
```

It all depends on your HTML structure and what your desired behavior is. If you are only going to target one element then using the id lookup with `down()` probably would work better. If you are going to have multiple child elements within the `#product_composite_configure` element then using the `$$()` selector with `invoke()` would mean any new elements would be affected as well without rewriting the script.

Comment: Thx for sharing this info with us :)

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things ? Try this:

```
var selectors = ["#product_composite_configure",".entry-edit",".buttons-set",".a-right",".scalable"];
selectors.forEach(function(e, i) {
   $$(e).each(function(elem) {
       elem.setAttribute("test","test");
   })
});
```

Comment: I got this in the firebug:           TypeError: $$(...).setAttribute is not a function
var BundleControl = Class.create();

Comment: Do `console.log(e)` instead to see what's `e`, I'm not familiar with prototype btw